# WebRole and WorkerRole Templates Missing in VS 2015

Tags: azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-webjobs, visual-studio-2015

I have looked far and wide for the answer to this.
In Visual Studio 2013 I can easily create a WebRole and WorkerRole solution but in VS 2015 all I can seem to do is create a Website and WebJob.

Has the WebRole and WorkerRole been removed?
If not can you explain to me where it is - or why it is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a new install of VS2015 you have to download and install the Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff687127.aspx#Install

Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET extends Visual Studio and to install the Azure tools:

- From Visual Studio's menu bar choose File -> New -> Project.
- From Installed Templates choose either the Visual Basic or Visual C# node,
  and then choose the Cloud node that contains a project template named Get Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET.

Note: This template only appears if you haven’t installed the Azure Tools.

- To download the tools, choose the OK button.
- An Azure Tools tab appears.
- To start the download, choose the Download Azure Tools button to open the web installer.
- Follow the instructions provided by the web installer to install the latest version of the Azure tools and the Azure SDK.

Azure Tools requires Internet Information Services (IIS) version 7, 7.5, 8, or Express. To install IIS or IIS Express, use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Note: You might have to restart Visual Studio before the Azure project templates appear.

Answer (score 5):

Download the Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2015 from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

It should force you to close Visual Studio, but if it doesn't, do so anyways. Once it's installed, you can reboot it.

When you go to add a new project, you can look under `Cloud` and then choose `Azure Cloud Service`. This will give you the same old familiar screen, where you can choose a Web Role or Worker Role:

[image: Azure Web Role]